# best way to compare two 2d-array

Tags: powershell

I have 2 Domain where I am taking ADuser which are Inactive form couple of days and storing both the ADusers in 2 different array and comparing them.
but I have problem with comparing both the array can anyone help me.

```
$obj =@()
$obj = Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq 
 $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp -SearchBase "OU=Active,DC=adtest,DC=com" | 
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=Disabled,*' } | select-object ObjectGUID, Name

$obj1 = @()
$obj1 = Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp -SearchBase "OU=Active,DC=adxyz,DC=com" | 
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike '*OU=Disabled,*' } |
select-object ObjectGUID, Name
$obj | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($i -in $obj.ObjectGUID -eq $j -in $obj1.ObjectsGUID) {
         }
}
```

i am expected to have same objectGUID as output.

Comment: Where do `$i` and `$j` come from?  That `ForEach-Object` is enumerating `$obj` so you'd want to test if the current pipeline element from `$obj`, `$_`, exists in `$obj1`: `if ($_ -in $obj1.ObjectGUID) { }`.  That's not going to be the best way, but a working way.

Comment: @BACON yes I want to test if the current pipeline element from $obj, $_, exists in $obj1: if ($_ -in $obj1.ObjectGUID) { }.

Comment: Did that work?  You just want to output objects with a GUID in both lists?  A small change of cmdlets, `$obj | Where-Object { $_.ObjectGUID -in $obj1.ObjectGUID }`, should do that for you.  By the way, a couple typos: in my previous comment the `if` statement should be comparing `$_.ObjectGUID` instead of just `$_`, and I notice in the original code you have `$obj1.ObjectsGUID` instead of `$obj1.ObjectGUID`.

Comment: @BACON Thank this is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this...

```bsh
$obj | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($i -in $obj.ObjectGUID -eq $j -in $obj1.ObjectsGUID) {
    }
}
```

...you are iterating through each element of `$obj`.  The `-in` operator will also iterate through its second operand, so you don't need to use that again for `$obj`.  `$i` and `$j` won't work since they're not defined anywhere.  You can, however, use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) [`$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#_) to access the current pipeline element from `$obj`...

```bsh
$obj | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.ObjectGUID -in $obj1.ObjectGUID) {
        $obj
    }
}
```

This will output to the pipeline any elements of `$obj` whose `ObjectGUID` property matches that of an element in `$obj1`.  A simpler way to do this would be with the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)...

```bsh
$obj | Where-Object { $_.ObjectGUID -in $obj1.ObjectGUID }
```

...or, for PowerShell 3.0 and above...

```bsh
$obj | Where-Object -Property 'ObjectGUID' -In -Value $obj1.ObjectGUID
```

...which can be written as simply...

```bsh
$obj | Where-Object ObjectGUID -in $obj1.ObjectGUID
```

None of these approaches are very efficient, however, because for each element in `$obj` the `-in` operator will perform a linear search through `$obj1`.  A simple solution is to use a [`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable) or [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) to look up users by their `ObjectGUID`.  We can use the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to retrieve such a `Hashtable`...

```bsh
$adxyzActiveUsersByObjectGUID = $obj1 | Group-Object -Property 'ObjectGUID' -AsHashTable
```

`$adxyzActiveUsersByObjectGUID` contains the user objects of `$obj1` indexed/keyed on their `ObjectGUID` property for fast retrieval.  Filtering can then be done using the [`Contains()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.contains)...

```bsh
$obj | Where-Object { $adxyzActiveUsersByObjectGUID.Contains($_.ObjectGUID) }
```

...or [item indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.item)...

```bsh
$obj | Where-Object { $adxyzActiveUsersByObjectGUID[$_.ObjectGUID] -ne $null }
```